# How to get expandble button on grid coloumn header

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I am trying to make expandable button on the header of grid. On click of that It will expand and then again click it will close.
I wrote a function for expanding with flag 1 and 0.

My question is how to place a switch button on header of grid column.

Here I tried.
By Design time just for reference.

```
columns: [{
    id: 'Sd',
    header: 'Study',
    width: 130,
    sortable: false,
    hideable: false,
    dataIndex: 'Stu'
}, {
    width: 130,
    header: '<u style="color:blue;cursor:pointer;" title="Click on to view by Days"  onclick="Fn_dayclick(0)">' +
        '<img alt="Click on to view by Days" style="vertical-align:bottom;" ' +
        'src="Images/508Images/group-expand.gif"> ' + "Subject" + '</u>',
    id: 'Sub',
    itemId: "Sub",
    dataIndex: 'Sub',
    hidden: false,
}, {
    width: 130,
    id: 'Ext',
    header: 'Exclude',
    dataIndex: 'Excl',
    hidden: false
}]
```

In Subject header i given that code with + button and on click it call Fn_dayclick(0). But where to give code for - button which I prepared. This is in the case where I am designing column in code.
What to do when my column is coming from xml. 
My code for Ajax

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'XML/Cohart.xml',
    scope: this,
    timeout: global_constants.TIMEOUT,
    method: "GET",
    disableCaching: true,
    failure: function(response) {
        utils.showOKErrorMsg(sdisMsg.ajaxRequestFailed);
    },
    success: function(response) {
        var datas = response.responseXML;
        Ext.each(datas.getElementsByTagName("HEADER"), function(header) {
            this.buildField(header);
            this.buildColumn(header);
        }, this);
        Ext.each(datas.getElementsByTagName("G"), function(columnData) {
            this.fieldLength = this.fields.length;
            this.record = [];
            for (i = 0; i < this.fieldLength; i++) {
                //this.record.push(columnData);
                var fieldName = this.fields[i].name
                this.record[fieldName] = columnData.getAttribute(fieldName);
            }
            this.data.push(this.record);
        }, this);
        this.store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields: this.fields
        });
        this.store.loadData(this.data);
    },
    //this.store.loadData(this.data);});

    buildField: function(header) {
        this.fields.push({
            name: header.getAttribute("DATAINDEX")
        });
    },
    buildColumn: function(header) {
        var hiddenflg = !(header.getAttribute("VISIBLE"));
        if (header.getAttribute("VISIBLE") == "false")
            hiddenflg = true;
        var strHeaderName = '';
        if ((Ext.isIE && !PC.common.isIE10()))
            strHeaderName = header.text;
        else
            strHeaderName = header.textContent;
        var strToolTip = "";
        this.columns.push({
            header: Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(strHeaderName),
            tooltip: strToolTip,
            dataIndex: header.getAttribute("DATAINDEX"),
            width: parseInt(header.getAttribute("LENGTH")),
            metaID: header.getAttribute("M"),
            enableHdMenu: false,
            hidden: hiddenflg,
            menuDisabled: true,
            sortable: false,
            scope: this,
            fixed: false,
            expanded: true
        });
    },
});
```

Shall I put in render or anywhere else. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want particular column header to be button with expandable then try this.

declare a variable and store your header in that. In if statement set header for that perticular column and in else statement set header for other columns.
in coloumn.push in place of header call your variable where you storing your header.

here is a code for you.

```
 var headerstu;
    if(header.getAttribute("DATAINDEX") === "SUB"){
        if(header.showPara){ // decelear a showPara as boolean in ur function
            headerstu = '<u style="color:blue;cursor:pointer;" title="Click on to view across Subject" onclick="Fn_Dayclick(1)">' +
                        '<img alt="Click on to view across Subject" style="vertical-align:bottom;" ' +
                        ' src="Images/508Images/group-expand.gif" />' +
                        '  ' + Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(strHeaderName) + '</u>';
        }else{
            headerstu = '<u style="color:blue;cursor:pointer;" title="Click on to view across Subject" onclick="Fn_Dayclick(0)">' +
                        '<img alt="Click on to view across Subject" style="vertical-align:bottom;" ' +
                        ' src="Images/508Images/group-close.gif" />' +
                        '  ' + Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(strHeaderName) + '</u>';
        }// take a groupclose image which is opposite to group-expand
    }else{
         headerstu = Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(strHeaderName);
    }
    this.columns.push({
        header: headerstu,
         tooltip: strToolTip,
        dataIndex: header.getAttribute("DATAINDEX"),
        width: parseInt(header.getAttribute("LENGTH")),
        metaID: header.getAttribute("M"),
        enableHdMenu: false,
        hidden: hiddenflg,
        menuDisabled: true,
        sortable: false,
        scope: this,
        fixed: false,
        expanded: true
    });
},
```

Also I am not tested your complete code like function which you given on onclick but I am sure you can get changeable button on expandable column.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly I wanted. Separate way to get header for different columns.  Thanks a ton.